# Receive and send an authorization token in Swagger

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-ui

I am creating a documentation page with Swagger, and I would like to automatically add the access token received from a correct `/login` call. I tried using

```
responseInterceptor: (responseObj) => {
  if(responseObj.obj.access_token !== 'undefined'){
    token = responseObj.obj.access_token;
  }
  return responseObj
}
```

to receive and store the token, and

```
requestInterceptor: (requestObj) => {
  if(token !== 'undefined') {
    requestObj.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
  return requestObj
}
```

to pass it onto subsequent requests through the header, however this only works for one call, after which the token reverts back to `null`.

How could I keep the `token` value from being reverted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by declaring token as a global variable.

```
//Checks any reponse obtained for an access token
responseInterceptor: (responseObj) => {
  if("access_token" in responseObj.obj){
    window.token = responseObj.obj.access_token;
  }
  return responseObj
},

//Adds the authorization to the request header if token has been set
requestInterceptor: (requestObj) => {
  if(window.token) {
    requestObj.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${window.token}`;
  }
  return requestObj
}
```

I'm new to JS and Swagger, so the answer wasn't obvious. I hope this helps someone eventually.